# android pushing notification with mqtt

Tags: android, mqtt

How can I save information from an android device to a database when clients first connect to the server, so I can be aware of which device I should push notifications to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, there's a lot of great information about MQTT on Android on [the MQTT.org wiki](http://mqtt.org/wiki/doku.php/mqtt_on_the_android_platform).

This question is less about Android or MQTT and more about uniquely identifying a client device, and managing data on the backend service. There's no single answer here, but your device's MQTT ClientID / identifier needs to be unique so e.g. you will want to generate an identifier on the client side which is unique before connecting to a broker. You probably want to establish a specific topic for push notifications to that device too. When initially provisioning a new client, squirrel that information away into a database of your choice so you know the topic to use to address an individual device.